# create multi row editing when clicked on buttons in table using ngx-datatable

Tags: angular5, ngx-datatable

Anybody knows how to create custom multi row editing with buttons in table using ngx-datatable (Or row(/multi-row) on selection changes to form editable when clicked on Edit button and cancel on cancel button) Plnkr sample code would be so helpful. Thanks in advance
I am using Angular 5.